# i lost many pages, need to recover and fix the error : Fatal exception of type "MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionAccessException"

Tags: xampp, mediawiki

mediawiki 1.32 installation on XAMPP on windows 10.

using it for few months, suddenly this error started coming in many pages :  Fatal exception of type "MediaWiki\Revision\RevisionAccessException"

cannot see my data, undo any changes or edit the page anymore, it's locked.

have lots of data on pages which i need to recover and make the page editable again.

the wiki site was created on media wiki 1.32

tried : rolling back to previous vesions of mediawiki, restoring the database, didn't work.

tried : moving the mediawiki & importing database on different system (linux, mysql, lighthttpd), didn't work.

Comment: If this happened without you doing anything risky (changing the DB, installing weird extensions...), you should probably [file a bug](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/).

Comment: @Tgr this bug is already filed. i am looking to recover typed text data from database, if that's possible.

Comment: Hard to say anything without more details (a stack trace at least).

Answer (score -1):

... There is no short answer, you should check the database schema and define where your text data is.
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout

Edit.
You may try this:

```
SELECT P.page_namespace, P.page_title, R.rev_id, C.content_id, C.content_address, Convert(T.old_text USING utf8)
FROM page P
INNER JOIN revision R ON R.rev_id=P.page_latest
INNER JOIN slots S ON R.rev_id = S.slot_revision_id
INNER JOIN content C ON S.slot_content_id=C.content_id
INNER JOIN text T ON Concat("tt:",T.old_id)=C.content_address
```

If you succes in extracting the data, be aware of namespaces and other metadata you may need to restore.

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Namespace

Comment: Any feedback its apreciated. I'm just learning that since 1.31 the structure change for texts references. I hope it helps.